# How to extend the Random Walk Algorithm to include also pre-segmented images according to this formula?

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image, random-walk

- I have the following formula to extend the mathematical expectaion of the original [random walk algorithm](http://vision.cse.psu.edu/people/chenpingY/paper/grady2006random.pdf) which is already implemented in [SciKit-Image segmentation](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/segmentation/random_walker_segmentation.py).
- I tried to implement the **Guided random walker** algorithm mentioned in this [paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15niGQKGsgIV1yCR-Dp1rh26Wwz1J4VYs/view?usp=sharing) by mimicking the Scikit-image implementation.
- but my implementation is not correct because of the mask Array **b**.
- #### How can I implement the following mathematical expectation correctly?

My code is down.

[image: Guided Random walk]

```
import numpy as np
import time
import scipy
from scipy import sparse, ndimage as ndi
from scipy.sparse.linalg import cg, spsolve
from skimage import img_as_float
from distutils.version import LooseVersion as Version
import functools
if Version(scipy.__version__) >= Version('1.1'):
    cg = functools.partial(cg, atol=0)

try:
    from pyamg import ruge_stuben_solver
    amg_loaded = True
except ImportError:
    amg_loaded = False

def make_graph_edges(image):

    if(len(image.shape)==2):
        # print(image.shape)
        n_x, n_y = image.shape
        vertices = np.arange(n_x * n_y ).reshape((n_x, n_y))
        edges_horizontal = np.vstack(( vertices[:, :-1].ravel(), vertices[:, 1:].ravel()))   # X *(Y-1)
        edges_vertical   = np.vstack(( vertices[   :-1].ravel(), vertices[1:   ].ravel()))   #(X-1)* Y  
        edges = np.hstack((edges_horizontal, edges_vertical))
    else:
        print('image shape is: ',image.shape)

    return edges

#===================================================================================

def compute_weights(image,mask,alpha, beta, eps=1.e-6):
    intra_gradients = np.concatenate([np.diff(image, axis=ax).ravel()
     for ax in [1, 0] ], axis=0) ** 2            # gradient ^2
    # 5-Connected
    inter_gradients = np.concatenate([np.diff(mask, axis=ax).ravel()
    for ax in [1, 0] ], axis=0)**2 
    #----------------------------------------
    # 1-Connected
    # inter_gradients = (image - mask)**2
    #----------------------------------------
    # Normalize gradients
    intra_gradients = (intra_gradients - np.amin(intra_gradients))/(np.amax(intra_gradients)- np.amin(intra_gradients))
    inter_gradients = (inter_gradients - np.amin(inter_gradients))/(np.amax(inter_gradients)- np.amin(inter_gradients)) 
    # All dimensions considered together in this standard deviation
    #------------------------------------------------------
    intra_scale_factor  = -beta  / (10 * image.std())
    intra_weights = np.exp(intra_scale_factor * intra_gradients)
    intra_weights += eps
    #------------------------------------------------------
    inter_scale_factor  = -alpha / (10 * image.std())
    inter_weights = np.exp(inter_scale_factor * inter_gradients)
    inter_weights += eps
    #------------------------------------------------------
    return -intra_weights, inter_weights # [W_old , w_new]
#=============================================================================

def build_matrices(image, mask, alpha=90, beta=130):
    edges_2D = make_graph_edges(image)

    intra_weights, inter_weights = compute_weights(image=image,mask=mask,alpha=alpha ,beta=beta, eps=1.e-6 )

    #================
    # Matrix Laplace
    #================    
    # Build the sparse linear system
    pixel_nb  = edges_2D.shape[1]  # N = n_x * (n_y - 1) * +  (n_x - 1) * n_y
    i_indices = edges_2D.ravel()   # Src - Dest
    j_indices = edges_2D[::-1].ravel() # Same list in reverse order ( Dest - Src)   
    stacked_intra = np.hstack((intra_weights, intra_weights)) # weights (S-->D, D-->S) are same because graph is undirected
    lap = sparse.coo_matrix((2*stacked_intra, (i_indices, j_indices)), shape=(pixel_nb, pixel_nb))
    lap.setdiag(-2*np.ravel(lap.sum(axis=0)))
    # print('Lap',lap.shape)
    Laplace = lap.tocsr()
    #================
    # Matrix Omega
    #================
    # Build the sparse linear system   
    stacked_inter = np.hstack((inter_weights, inter_weights)) # weights (S-->D, D-->S) are same because graph is undirected
    Omeg = sparse.coo_matrix((2*stacked_inter, (i_indices, j_indices)), shape=(pixel_nb, pixel_nb))
    Omeg.setdiag(2*np.ravel((image-mask)**2))
    # print('Omeg',Omeg.shape)
    Omega = Omeg.tocsr()
    #================
    # Matrix A
    #================     
    # Build the sparse linear system  
    weights = Omega.copy() 
    firstColumn  = weights.sum(axis=1)/2
    otherColumns = sparse.csr_matrix((weights.shape[0],weights.shape[1]-1))
    Mat_A = sparse.hstack((firstColumn, otherColumns))
    # print('A',Mat_A.shape)
    return Laplace, Omega, Mat_A
#=============================================================================

def build_linear_system(image, labels, nlabels, beta):
    """
    Build the matrix A and rhs B of the linear system to solve.
    A and B are two blocks of the laplacian of the image graph.
    """
    labels2 = labels.copy()
    labels  = labels.ravel()

    indices = np.arange(labels.size) # indices of all vertices
    seeds_mask = labels > 0          # Keep only lables withL_out Background
    unlabeled_indices = indices[~seeds_mask] # U
    seeds_indices = indices[seeds_mask]      # M


    lap_sparse,omega_sparse, A_sparse = build_matrices(image=image, mask=labels2,
                                  beta=beta)
    A_sparse = A_sparse.tocsr()
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    seeds = labels[seeds_mask]
    seeds_mask = sparse.csc_matrix(np.hstack([np.atleast_2d(seeds == lab).T
     for lab in range(1, nlabels + 1)]))
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Laplacian
    #=============
    rows_L = lap_sparse[unlabeled_indices, :]
    lap_sparse = rows_L[:, unlabeled_indices]   # size =     U    x U
    B_L = -rows_L[:, seeds_indices]               # size = N^2(U+M) x U

    rhs_L = B_L.dot(seeds_mask)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Omega
    #=============
    rows_O = omega_sparse[unlabeled_indices, :]
    omega_sparse = rows_O[:, unlabeled_indices] # size =     U    x U
    B_O = -rows_O[:, seeds_indices]             # size = N^2(U+M) x U

    rhs_O = B_O.dot(seeds_mask)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    rows_A = A_sparse[unlabeled_indices, :]
    A_sparse = rows_A[:, unlabeled_indices]     # size =     U    x U
    B_A = -rows_A[:, seeds_indices]             # size = N^2(U+M) x U

    rhs_A = B_A.dot(seeds_mask)
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    return lap_sparse, omega_sparse, A_sparse, rhs_L, rhs_O, rhs_A
#=============================================================================
def solve_linear_system(lap_sparse,omega_sparse,A_sparse, B_L, B_O, B_A,tol):

    if not amg_loaded:
        print('"cg_mg" not available, it requires pyamg to be installed. ',
             'The "cg_j" mode will be used instead.')
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Laplace
    #==========
    maxiter = 30
    lap_sparse = lap_sparse.tocsr()
    mlL = ruge_stuben_solver(lap_sparse)
    ML = mlL.aspreconditioner(cycle='V')

    cg_L_out_L = [
        cg(lap_sparse, B_L[:, i].toarray(), tol=tol, M=ML, maxiter=maxiter)
        for i in range(B_L.shape[1])]

    if np.any([info > 0 for _, info in cg_L_out_L]):
        print("Laplace Conjugate gradient convergence to tolerance not achieved. ",
             "\nConsider decreasing beta to improve system conditionning.")

    XL = np.asarray([x1 for x1, _ in cg_L_out_L])
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Omega
    #==========
    omega_sparse = omega_sparse.tocsr()
    mlO = ruge_stuben_solver(omega_sparse)
    MO = mlO.aspreconditioner(cycle='V')
    maxiter = 30
    B_O = np.nan_to_num(B_O)
    omega_sparse = np.nan_to_num(omega_sparse)
    cg_L_out_O = [
        cg(omega_sparse, B_O[:, i].toarray(), tol=tol, M=MO, maxiter=maxiter)
        for i in range(B_O.shape[1])]

    if np.any([info > 0 for _, info in cg_L_out_O]):
        print("Omega Conjugate gradient convergence to tolerance not achieved. ",
             "\nConsider decreasing beta to improve system conditionning.")

    XO = np.asarray([x1 for x1, _ in cg_L_out_O])
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Mat_A
    #==========
    A_sparse = A_sparse.tocsr()
    mlA = ruge_stuben_solver(A_sparse)
    MA = mlA.aspreconditioner(cycle='V')
    maxiter = 30
    cg_L_out_A = [
        cg(A_sparse, B_A[:, i].toarray(), tol=tol, M=MA, maxiter=maxiter)
        for i in range(B_A.shape[1])]

    if np.any([info > 0 for _, info in cg_L_out_A]):
        print("Mat_A Conjugate gradient convergence to tolerance not achieved. ",
             "\nConsider decreasing beta to improve system conditionning.")

    XA = np.asarray([x1 for x1, _ in cg_L_out_A])
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    return XL, XO, XA
#=======================================================================
def preprocess(labels):

    label_values, inv_idx = np.unique(labels, return_inverse=True)

    if not (label_values == 0).any():
        print('Random walker only segments unlabeled areas, where ',
             '\nlabels == 0. No zero valued areas in labels were ',
             '\nfound. Returning provided labels.')

        return labels, None, None, None, None

    # If some labeled pixels are isolated inside pruned zones, prune them
    # as well and keep the labels for the final L_output

    null_mask = labels == 0
    pos_mask = labels > 0
    mask = labels >= 0

    fill = ndi.binary_propagation(null_mask, mask=mask)
    isolated = np.logical_and(pos_mask, np.logical_not(fill))

    pos_mask[isolated] = False

    # If the array has pruned zones, be sure that no isolated pixels
    # exist between pruned zones (they could not be determined)
    if label_values[0] < 0 or np.any(isolated):
        isolated = np.logical_and(
            np.logical_not(ndi.binary_propagation(pos_mask, mask=mask)),
            null_mask)

        labels[isolated] = -1
        if np.all(isolated[null_mask]):
            print('All unlabeled pixels are isolated, they could not be ',
                 '\ndetermined by the random walker algorithm.')
            return labels, None, None, None, None

        mask[isolated] = False
        mask = np.atleast_2d(mask)
    else:
        mask = None

    # Reorder label values to have consecutive integers (no gaps)
    zero_idx = np.searchsorted(label_values, 0)
    labels = np.atleast_2d(inv_idx.reshape(labels.shape) - zero_idx)

    nlabels = label_values[zero_idx + 1:].shape[0]

    inds_isolated_seeds = np.nonzero(isolated)
    isolated_values = labels[inds_isolated_seeds]

    return labels, nlabels, mask, inds_isolated_seeds, isolated_values
#=========================================================================
def random_walker(image, labels, beta=130, gamma=0.4, tol=1.e-3, copy=True, return_full_prob=False):

    if (image.ndim !=2):
        raise ValueError('For non-multichannel input, image must be of '
                         'dimension 2.')
    if image.shape != labels.shape:
        raise ValueError('Incompatible image and labels shapes.')
    # image = np.atleast_2d(img_as_float(image))[..., np.newaxis]
    image = img_as_float(image)#

    labels_shape = labels.shape
    labels_dtype = labels.dtype

    if copy:
        labels = np.copy(labels)

    (labels, nlabels, mask,
     inds_isolated_seeds, isolated_values) = preprocess(labels)

    if isolated_values is None:
        # No non isolated zero valued areas in labels were
        # found. Returning provided labels.
        if return_full_prob:
            # Return the concatenation of the masks of each unique label
            return np.concatenate([np.atleast_2d(labels == lab)
                                   for lab in np.unique(labels) if lab > 0],
                                  axis=-1)
        return labels

    # Build the linear system (lap_sparse, B)
    lap_sparse,omega_sparse,A_sparse,B_L,B_O,B_A = build_linear_system(image,
     labels, nlabels, beta)

    # Solve the linear system lap_sparse X = B
    # where X[i, j] is the probability that a marker of label i arrives
    # first at pixel j by anisotropic diffusion.
    XL, XO, XA = solve_linear_system(lap_sparse,omega_sparse,A_sparse, B_L, B_O, B_A,tol)

    # Build the L_output according to return_full_prob value
    # Put back labels of isolated seeds
    labels[inds_isolated_seeds] = isolated_values
    labels = labels.reshape(labels_shape)
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if return_full_prob:
        mask = labels == 0

        #===========#
        # Laplacian #
        #===========#
        L_out = np.zeros((nlabels,) + labels_shape)
        for lab, (label_prob_L, prob_L) in enumerate(zip(L_out, XL), start=1):
            label_prob_L[mask] = prob_L
            label_prob_L[labels == lab] = 1
        #===========#
        #   Omega   #
        #===========#
        O_out = np.zeros((nlabels,) + labels_shape)
        for lab, (label_prob_O, prob_O) in enumerate(zip(O_out, XO), start=1):
            label_prob_O[mask] = prob_O
            label_prob_O[labels == lab] = 1 
        #===========#
        #   Mat_A   #
        #===========#
        A_out = np.zeros((nlabels,) + labels_shape)
        for lab, (label_prob_A, prob_A) in enumerate(zip(O_out, XO), start=1):
            label_prob_A[mask] = prob_O
            label_prob_A[labels == lab] = 1       
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    else:
        #===========#
        # Laplacian #
        #===========#
        XL = np.argmax(XL, axis=0) + 1
        L_out = labels.astype(labels_dtype)
        L_out[labels == 0] = XL
        #===========#
        #   Omega   #
        #===========#
        XO = np.argmax(XO, axis=0) + 1
        O_out = labels.astype(labels_dtype)
        O_out[labels == 0] = XO
        #===========#
        #   Mat_A   #
        #===========#
        XA = np.argmax(XA, axis=0) + 1
        A_out = labels.astype(labels_dtype)
        A_out[labels == 0] = XA
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    return 0.5*L_out + 0.5*gamma*A_out - 2*O_out
```

Comment: I think you might not be getting too much traction on this question because there's too much to read. You'd likely get more responses if you put up a minimal example of exactly what's going wrong. For instance, why can you not just use successive `numpy.dot` operations to get the expectation you want?

Comment: @Aaron I think because `Xu` the unmarked labels aren't constants, they are variables which has to be minimized, and not calculated directly.

Comment: That would depend on the implementation (it's not true, for instance, if you're using a sampling based approach), but I haven't read your code so I don't know anything about that. That was kinda my point. If you had a minimal example, your comment would have been readily apparent.
Can you update your question with a minimal example of the issue you're having?
(see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Aaron for me this is the minimal working example, because each step in the code depends on the other steps, and maybe the mistake is resultant from any function of them, that's why the code seems to be long, I can't shorten it more.

Comment: Fair enough. You might still want to give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a quick read. It's there for your benefit -- written by the people at stack overflow.